# Quality indicators ADS-B out & Ground Station receiver

Tags: ads-b, transponder

I have a question about quality indicators parameters:
I discussed with a pilot about quality indicators .
We talked about NIC and NACp parameters
I received his quality indicators in my ADS-B Ground Station but we noticed that is not the same value ex :

```
                NIC aircraft:10

                NACp aircraft: 10

                NIC ground station : 8

                NACp GS : 11
```

And he tell me it should be the same value between them (aircraft, ground station)
Is there any explanation about this and what is the tolerance btw the transponder and GS ?

Comment: These are digitally encoded messages. If the ground station is displaying the data it decoded from the aircraft then either it is coded improperly or it was encoded improperly by the transmitter  or you’re not looking at what you think you’re looking at.

Comment: How does the pilot know what the ADS-B quality indicators were in the aircraft? Normally this information is not known to pilots.

Comment: @DeltaLima thanks for your support , this aircraft is for flight check , to Calibrate VOR,ILS,PSR,MSSR-MODES , so it's equiped with special .    Please can answer to this question # ADS-B MOPS & quality indicators I added before and no one answered to this question. Thanks again